# SQL Server 2014 Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-server-2014

Please take a look at the code and help me on the last part, **--put all together = fail !!!**

I wanted to generate a string for executing `sp_executesql` but I'm getting an error at the end. I also tried open cursor but it error out too.

Basically I'm trying to get actual row count per column per table for all tables 
because general rowcount want give you if new column added and populated.

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
-- Create view to hold the dataset
Alter view vColumnSchema
AS
with myColumnName
As
(
Select      TOP (100) PERCENT 
            GetDate() As create_date,
            @@SERVERNAME As Server_Name,
            DB_Name() AS database_name,
            c.[object_id],
            s.name AS [schema_name],                      
            t.name as table_name,
            c.name as column_name,
            p.rows AS NUM_ROWS,
            c.[precision]                                     
from        sys.tables as t
INNER JOIN  sys.columns as c with(nolock) on t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
INNER JOIN  sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id 
INNER JOIN  sys.partitions AS p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN  sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE       t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND         i.object_id > 255 
AND         i.index_id <= 1
And         s.name is not null
Order by    s.name,
            t.name       
)
Select      Top 100 percent 
            create_date,
            Server_Name,
            database_name, 
            [schema_name],
            table_name,
            column_name,
            NUM_ROWS,
            case when precision = 0 then
            'Select Count('+column_name+')'+' from ' +[schema_name]+'.'+table_name+ ' where '+column_name+'<> '''' '  
            else 
            'Select Count(' +column_name+')'+' from ' +[schema_name]+ '.'+table_name+' where '+column_name+'> 0'   
            END as ColumnCount,
            case when precision = 0 
            then ' <> '''' '    
            Else '> 0' 
            END As WhereClause                  
from        myColumnName
Order by    [schema_name],
            table_name


GO
select * from vColumnSchema 
where table_name = 'ProductCostHistory'
go

select * from Production.ProductCostHistory -- 395 records
--pick one record and test it = pass
Select Count(EndDate) from Production.ProductCostHistory where EndDate<> '' --200 records

GO
--test = pass on both whereClause
Declare @Column_name nvarchar(50) = 'EndDate' 
Declare @Schema_Name nvarchar(20) = 'Production'
declare @table_name nvarchar(50)  = 'ProductCostHistory'
declare @whereClause nvarchar(5) =  '<> '''' ' 
declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) ='
select count('+@Column_name+') as ColumnCount from ' +@Schema_Name+'.'+@table_name+' where '+@Column_name+' '+@WhereClause+'
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext 
GO
--examine each column = pass
Declare @Column_name nvarchar(50) = 'select Column_name from vColumnSchema'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Column_name
GO
Declare @schema_name nvarchar(50) = 'select schema_name from vColumnSchema'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @schema_name
GO
declare @table_name nvarchar(50)  = 'select table_name from vColumnSchema'
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @table_name
GO
declare @WhereClause nvarchar(50)  = 'select WhereClause from vColumnSchema'
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @WhereClause 
GO
--put all together = fail !!!
declare @Column_name nvarchar(50) = 'select Column_name from vColumnSchema'
declare @schema_name nvarchar(50) = 'select schema_name from vColumnSchema'
declare @table_name nvarchar(50)  = 'select table_name from vColumnSchema'
declare @WhereClause nvarchar(5)  = 'select WhereClause from vColumnSchema';
declare @sqltext nvarchar(max)    ='
select count('+@Column_name+') as ColumnCount from ' +@Schema_Name+'.'+@table_name+' where '+@Column_name+' '+@WhereClause+' 
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext
go
```

Comment: Instead of executing that final @sqltext, try printing it. You'll see it becomes something that CAN'T be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of rows per column per table:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
N'SELECT '''
    + t.name + ''' AS TableName, ''' 
    + c.name + ''' AS ColName, COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') AS [RowCount] FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' UNION ALL' + CHAR(10)       
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
    t.type = 'U'
    AND c.system_type_id <> 35


SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11)

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it produce same results as Partition row numbers which show you all column with same count

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what your end game is But this might help and does not use dynamic  sql ...

You can put the number of columns in your original query without a CTE
This puts the col count in the original select

```
Select      TOP (100) PERCENT 
            GetDate() As create_date,
            @@SERVERNAME As Server_Name,
            DB_Name() AS database_name,
            c.[object_id],
            s.name AS [schema_name],                      
            t.name as table_name,
            c.name as column_name,
            p.rows AS NUM_ROWS,
            c.[precision] ,
            (Select COUNT(c2.object_id) 
               FROM sys.columns c2 
              INNER JOIN sys.tables t2 ON t2.object_id = c2.object_id 
              WHERE t2.object_id = t.object_id 
              GROUP BY c2.object_id)  as ColCountThisTbl                                     
from        sys.tables as t
INNER JOIN  sys.columns as c with(nolock) on t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
INNER JOIN  sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id 
INNER JOIN  sys.partitions AS p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN  sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE       t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND         i.object_id > 255 
AND         i.index_id <= 1
And         s.name is not null
Order by    s.name,
            t.name `enter code here`
```